# FOP migrating to newer version: Empty Cells are not allowed

Tags: apache, pdf, apache-fop

We are currently still using fop v0.2 and want to upgrade to fop v2.1. We are currently testing it with the command line interface and getting a lot errors due to empty cells in our `.xls` file:

> While FOP 0.20.5 allowed you to have empty fo:table-cell elements, the
>   new code will complain about that (unless relaxed validation is
>   enabled) because the specification demands at least one block-level
>   element ((%block;)+, see XSL-FO 1.1, 6.7.10) inside an fo:table-cell
>   element.

Is there a way to "fix" all of those errors without manually editing file after file?
We found the `-r` param for "relaxed" mode, but the errors are still not solved / disappearing. Is there a quick workaround?

Comment: If you think that what you observer is contradicting the documented behaviour, the best idea probably is to file a bug via the [fop jiira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP)